# Trying to swipe with nightwatch.js and appium. Why isn't this working?

Tags: javascript, appium, nightwatch.js

I have this code:

```
module.exports = {
  "@tags": ["demo"],
  "demo_test_name": function (client) {
    client.url("https://www.google.com");
    client.waitForElementPresent("body", 2000);
    client.swipe({
      startX: 75,
      startY: 500,
      endX: 75,
      endY: 0,
      duration: 800
    });
  },
  before: function (client) {
    var wd = require("wd");
    client.swipe = function (opts) {
      var action = new wd.TouchAction(this);
      action
        .press({
          x: opts.startX,
          y: opts.startY
        })
        .wait(opts.duration)
        .moveTo({
          x: opts.endX,
          y: opts.endY
        })
        .release();
      return action.perform();
    };
  },
```

I'm receiving this error.

```
this.driver.performTouchAction is not a function
```

Is there a reason this isn't working because of nightwatch? I've been working on getting swiping working in nightwatch for MONTHS now. This is the closest I've gotten. There's literally no documentation out there on this.

Comment: i am looking for this too, did you have any idea?

Comment: Not all drivers support touch actions.